# Uploading different versions of the same app to the App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I have an iOS app in the App Store and I want to use my app in different countries. So I wonder if it's possible to upload a different version for each country.

For example, I want to update Turkey's app but I want to hold the old version of an app on the UK market.

Answer (score 3):

There are essentially two options to consider:

1. Using **localized models/controllers** in order to display a different content to users with different locales. [Here's the Apple Developer guide about localizing your app.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)
2. Creating **different configurations** with different Bundle ID suffixes and treating the them as separate apps. [You can read more about configuration handling here.](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/configuration-handling-in-xcode-44d9a3e0388b)

I'd recommend the first one for most projects, since it's easier to handle one app than several ones. However, it's up to you and the project which one you'll choose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hold a version in different countries say for example If your app is published in 2 countries then next version will be automatically available in that 2 the countries because does not allow it.

If you want can add or remove the countries but if we talk about version holding on some countries that is not possible